# How to drop rows in python based on null values

Tags: python, pandas, null

Hello: I have the following code that gives me a count of the number of null values in a column:

`df_null = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]`

`df[df_null].isnull().sum()`

The result is an index with the column name and number of null values:

```
col1 10  
col2 20  
col3 30
```

What I want to do is drop all the rows/records in columns that have less than 15 null values. I have gone through the columns manually and dropped the rows/records using the following:

`df.dropna(subset=['col_name'], axis=0, inplace=True)`

That works fine. But what I would like to do is automate the process so I don't have to manually go through each column and drop the null rows/records manually.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your efforts in form code, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then. That will give us more clarity on question cheers

Answer (score 2):

Check with

```
s = df.isnull().sum()
dfnew = df.loc[:, (s>15)|(s==0)]
# the first condition will keep column with more than 15 null, then second , will keep all column without have NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

Keep only the columns with at least `n` `non-NaN` values

```
n=len(df)-15


 df.dropna(thresh=n, axis=1)
```